# Blacklist network ranges Docker is allowed to use for its containers (swarm mode)

Tags: docker, networking, docker-daemon

Basically I need to blacklist an IP range (and maybe multiple ranges) so that Docker can use any other IPs for its containers BUT IPs in this range.

Assume I have my docker nodes in a swarm of n nodes. They are in IP range `10.1.1.0/24`. There are multiple other VMs in this IP range like a VPN Server, a firewall, etc.

Can I restrict Docker from assigning IPs from this range to containers it starts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Docker should avoid using a network if there's a route to that network (see `ip r`). You can whitelist networks that docker is allowed to use with configurations in several places:

- You can adjust `bip` in `/etc/docker/daemon.json` which controls the docker bridge network named bridge. This needs to be set to a gateway ip with CIDR notation.
- You can adjust `default-address-pools` in `/etc/docker/daemon.json` which is a list of CIDR blocks for all other bridge networks.
- You can pass `--default-addr-pool` when initializing a swarm to a CIDR block for overlay networks.

Make sure the two pools are large enough to create multiple networks, e.g. a `/16` subnet to allow creation of 256 `/24` networks.

More details of this are available in my [DockerCon presentation](https://sudo-bmitch.github.io/presentations/dc2019/tips-and-tricks-of-the-captains.html#address-pools) (press `P` for presenter notes).

Comment: That is great knowledge. Thanks a lot!